# What classes/interfaces i will need to implement and Activity like "Setting" in android 3.1?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am wondering if i could implement setting activity in my own application just looking like the Built-in Setting application in android 3.1.

as you know Built-in Setting application looks like:
[image: Built-in Setting application looks like]

What concepts and classes i will need to accomplish my own activity same like this default one.

For example i need some options on the left side, on clicking each option on left i could pick up/see its values on right side..

My desired activity look like this:
[image: My desired activity looks like this]

Please explain the layout design in general (and in brief if possible). Any tutorials, any documentation or relavent example will be highly helpfull..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for, are [Fragments.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html)

Fragments can be used to fill a part of the screen, while doing something else entirely in a different one.
In your example you can create a main activity that contains two `Fragments`.  One `Fragment` controls the list on the left, the other one controls the main content area for your options.
By replacing the current `Fragment` in your content area with a different one on the press of a button, you can achieve the behavior you are looking for.

For the options menu, it looks like a [PreferenceFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html).

Sadly I can't provide any example code right now, but here is a tutorialthat should help you get started:

- [Android User Interface Design: Working With Fragments](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_fragments/)

Comment: Thank you sir i think i can move on now.. After reading the documentations

Comment: No problem. Could you accept my answer as the correct answer (if it was what you were looking for)? This takes it of the unanswered questions lists, and improves your reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Try [PreferenceActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html) or better still google for "preference android"